# How to use dojo or esriRequest object to get pdf that is stream in a byte array

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.4

I have an SOE that creates a pdf and streams it back in the response and it works great.

How can I call it using dojo or the esriRequest object to call the SOE and display the resulting pdf in a new window?

I see the esriRequest has a handleAs that can be set to document, but I fail to see how it is implemented.  I have seen examples of using dojo.io.iframe, but I prefer not to use a deprecated library.

```
var downloadPdfIframeName = "downloadPdfIframe"; 
var iframe = dojo.io.iframe.create(downloadPdfIframeName);
dojo.io.iframe.setSrc(iframe, url, true);
```

I would be nice if I could just use straight javascript and do something like window.open(encodeURIComponent(url)), but the url would be too long after I add all the parameters to the querystring and it would have to be a post request.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else has a similar problem, this is what I ended up doing:

```
var requestHandle = esriRequest({
                url: baseURL,
                content: content,
                handleAs: 'arraybuffer',
                callbackParamName: 'callback'
            });
            requestHandle.then(
                function (response) {
                     var file = new Blob([response], {
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                    //IE work around
                    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, 'ConsumptionReport.pdf');
                    }
                    else {
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        //window.open(fileURL);
                        // create an anchor and click on it.
                        var ancorTag = document.createElement('a');
                        ancorTag.href = fileURL; ancorTag.target = '_blank';
                        ancorTag.download = 'ConsumptionReport.pdf';
                        document.body.appendChild(ancorTag);
                        ancorTag.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(ancorTag);
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    var s = error;
                }
            );
```